# ModuleNotFoundError on pip install

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm a beginner in Python, using Python version 3.6.5.
Downloaded the source code from github, and I am unable to download/install modules using `pip install <<module name>>`

On running the initial `.py` script, I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvutils.cvdetector'
```

On further analysis, I found the code `from cvutils.cvdetector import CvDetector` in one of the internal modules.
On `pip install cvutils.cvdetector` on command prompt, the error I got was

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cvutils.cvdetector 
(from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cvutils.cvdetector
```

`cvutils` is already installed in `..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\cvutils`. Is there any other dependency I must add for this to work?

Comment: No module named <package> points to the missing module. If you see cvutils folder and not cvdetector. Consider running <pip install cvutils> afresh. You should also check for pip versions.

Comment: Uninstalled and installed `cvutils`, and tried running `pip install cvutils.detector` on CMD. Same error faced.

Comment: Try 'pip install cvutils'. Not  the big name

Comment: `cvutils` certainly doesn't have any `cvdetector`. Where from have you got that import? I cannot find any suitable `cvdetector` in the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem the other day.

First, you can try running `python -m pip install <module_name>`. Sometimes depending on how your environment is set up, just running `pip install <module_name>` doesn't work.

If that doesn't fix your problem you can uninstall Python and manually delete all related directories that were created upon install (mine was located in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python)`. I did this and upon reinstall, I no longer had the error.